# Making use of insets to pad content in WebView on Android

Tags: android, css, responsive-design, android-webview, mobile-website

We have a full-screen `WebView` that renders below the status bar in an Android app. What is the correct and preferred solution in order for the web view content to render correctly below the status bar, insetting / padding the content according to the height of the status bar?

Here's an example, considering that the image, title and navigation need to be part of the Web Page:

[image]